# How to use the TopoViewer in the QGIS DB Manager?

Tags: qgis, postgis, topology

I'm just wondering what the TopoViewer in QGIS is doing. DB Manager (PostGIS) says 'Schema "schemaname" is not registered in topology.topology'. Unfortunately there is no help available and I can't find a manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function automatically adds the layers of an *topology* schema (nodes, edges, faces) to the current project. The layer representations are preformatted in order to look decent and visualising the crucial information (e.g. left face_id, right face_id...) after adding them.

A topology schema is created as soon as the function `topology.CreateTopology('name', srid, tolerance)` is used to create a topology.

If you are not using the PostGIS topology datamodel, you can ignore that function.